# AJAX POST and Plus Sign ( + ) -- How to Encode?

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, encode, decode

I'm POSTing the contents of a form field via AJAX to a PHP script and using JavaScript to `escape(field_contents)`.  The problem is that any plus signs are being stripped out and replaced by spaces.  How can I safely 'encode' the plus sign and then appropriately 'decode' it on the PHP side?

Comment: to clarify, I was using escape(field_contents), not encode

Answer (score 178, accepted):

Use `encodeURIComponent()` in JS and in PHP you should receive the correct values.

Note: When you access `$_GET`, `$_POST` or `$_REQUEST` in PHP, you are retrieving values that have already been decoded.

Example:

In your JS:

```
// url encode your string
var string = encodeURIComponent('+'); // "%2B"
// send it to your server
window.location = 'http://example.com/?string='+string; // http://example.com/?string=%2B
```

On your server:

```
echo $_GET['string']; // "+"
```

It is only the raw HTTP request that contains the url encoded data.

For a GET request you can retrieve this from the `URI. $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` or `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`. For a urlencoded POST, `file_get_contents('php://stdin')`

NB:

`decode()` only works for single byte encoded characters. It will not work for the full UTF-8 range.

eg:

```
text = "\u0100"; // Ā
// incorrect
escape(text); // %u0100 
// correct
encodeURIComponent(text); // "%C4%80"
```

Note: `"%C4%80"` is equivalent to: `escape('\xc4\x80')`

Which is the byte sequence (`\xc4\x80`) that represents `Ā` in UTF-8. So if you use `encodeURIComponent()` your server side must know that it is receiving UTF-8. Otherwise PHP will mangle the encoding.

Comment: One follow-up:  When I encodeURIComponent(text) and text includes characters like the smart quote (&rsqo;), the php script seems to see junk characters.  I assume it's a charset problem, but I don't know how to resolve it.  I'm doing the AJAX POST with "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8", and I'm using PHP5 on the server side.

Comment: How are you viewing these characters? You have to make sure the browser knows it is UTF-8. In HTML you can set `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">` or `<meta charset="UTF-8">` you can also set it in PHP with the Content-Type HTTP Header. `header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8');` PS: &rsqo; does not decode in the browser (FF3.5).

Comment: I had a problem with the plus (+) character changing into space. Everything else went fine in UTF8. I had good luck using with encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(rootObject)). Thank you!

Comment: When running into this problem with passwords (which were collected via a javascript form post) I solved it with password = encodeURIComponent(password).   When passed to PHP, the encoded POST value of password works out correctly.

Answer (score 22):

In JavaScript try:

```
encodeURIComponent()
```

and in PHP:

```
urldecode($_POST['field']);
```

Comment: encodeURIComponent is the right answer — but as it generates URL encoded data and not HTML encoded data, html_entity_encode is way off.

Comment: `urldecode` is also way off as PHP will decode it automatically before populating `$_POST`.

Answer (score 5):

The hexadecimal value you are looking for is `%2B`

To get it automatically in PHP run your string through `urlencode($stringVal)`. And then run it rhough `urldecode($stringVal)` to get it back.

<strike>If you want the JavaScript to handle it, use `escape( str )`</strike>

**Edit**

After @bobince's comment I did more reading and he is correct. 
Use `encodeURIComponent(str)` and `decodeURIComponent(str)`. Escape will not convert the characters, only escape them with `\`'s

Comment: *Don't* use `escape` (or `unescape`) in JavaScript; they aren't the same as URL-encoding and will go wrong for + and any non-ASCII Unicode characters. encodeURIComponent/decodeURIComponent is almost always what you want.

Answer (score 4):

To make it more interesting and to hopefully enable less hair pulling for someone else. 
Using python, built dictionary for a device which we can use curl to configure.

Problem: `{"timezone":"+5"}  //throws an error " 5"`

Solution: `{"timezone":"%2B"+"5"}  //Works`

So, in a nutshell:

```
var = {"timezone":"%2B"+"5"}
json = JSONEncoder().encode(var)
subprocess.call(["curl",ipaddress,"-XPUT","-d","data="+json])
```

Thanks to this post!

Answer (score 0):

If you have to do a curl in php, you should use `urlencode()` from PHP but individually!

```
strPOST = "Item1=" . $Value1 . "&Item2=" . urlencode("+")
```

If you do `urlencode(strPOST)`, you will bring you another problem, you will have one Item1 and & will be change %xx value and be as one value, see down here the return!

Example 1

```
$strPOST = "Item1=" . $Value1 . "&Item2=" . urlencode("+") will give Item1=Value1&Item2=%2B
```

Example 2

```
$strPOST = urlencode("Item1=" . $Value1 . "&Item2=+") will give Item1%3DValue1%26Item2%3D%2B
```

Example 1 is the good way to prepare string for POST in curl

Example 2 show that the receptor will not see the equal and the ampersand to distinguish both value!

Answer (score -1):

my problem was with the accents (á É ñ ) and the plus sign (+) when i to try to save javascript "code examples" to mysql:

my solution (not the better way, but it works):

javascript:

```
function replaceAll( text, busca, reemplaza ){
  while (text.toString().indexOf(busca) != -1)
  text = text.toString().replace(busca,reemplaza);return text;
}


function cleanCode(cod){
code = replaceAll(cod , "|", "{1}" ); // error | palos de explode en java
code = replaceAll(code, "+", "{0}" ); // error con los signos mas   
return code;
}
```

function to save:

```
function save(pid,code){
code = cleanCode(code); // fix sign + and |
code = escape(code); // fix accents
var url = 'editor.php';
var variables = 'op=save';
var myData = variables +'&code='+ code +'&pid='+ pid +'&newdate=' +(new Date()).getTime();    
var result = null;
$.ajax({
datatype : "html",
data: myData,  
url: url,
success : function(result) {
    alert(result); // result ok                     
},
}); 
} // end function
```

function in php:

```
<?php
function save($pid,$code){
    $code= preg_replace("[\{1\}]","|",$code);
    $code= preg_replace("[\{0\}]","+",$code);
    mysql_query("update table set code= '" . mysql_real_escape_string($code) . "' where pid='$pid'");
}
?>
```