# Unable to send '+' through AJAX post?

Tags: ajax, post

I am using Ajax POST method to send data, but i am not able to send '+'(operator to the server i.e if i want to send 1+ or 20k+ it will only send 1 or 20k..just wipe out '+') 
HTML code goes here..

```
<form method='post' onsubmit='return false;' action='#'>
  <input type='input' name='salary' id='salary' />
  <input type='submit' onclick='submitVal();' />
</form>
```

and javascript code goes here,

```
function submitVal()
{
     var sal=document.getElementById("salary").value;
     alert(sal);
     var request=getHttpRequest();
     request.open('post','updateSal.php',false);
     request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
     request.send("sal="+sal);

     if(request.readyState == 4)
     {
        alert("update");
     }
}

           function getHttpRequest()
           {
               var request=false;
               if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
               {
                   request=new XMLHttpRequest();
               }
               else if(window.ActiveXObject)
               {
                   try
                   {
                       request=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                   }
                   catch(e)
                   {
                       try
                       {
                           request=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                       }
                       catch(e)
                       {
                           request=false;
                       }
                   }
               }

               return request;
           }
```

in the function submitVal() it first alert's the salary value as it is(if 1+ then alerts 1+), but when it is posted it just post's value without '+' operator which is needed...
is it any problem with query string, as the PHP backend code is working fine...

Comment: this question has be already answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373414/ajax-post-and-plus-sign-how-to-encode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
request.send("sal="+encodeURIComponent(sal));
```

The + is interpreted as an space on the server side so you need to encode the string first.

More info here:

> > http://xkr.us/articles/javascript/encode-compare/

Comment: yeah! it works, it was taking + as a space... thank you Tatu Ulmanen

Answer (score 1):

You need to encode sal in request.send("sal="+sal). You'll probably find that if sal was equal to "foo & bar", you would end up with just "foo" on the server since the & needs to be encoded too. So:

```
request.send("sal=" + encodeURIComponent(sal)); // updated example
```

However, rather than doing this all by hand, you should think about using a library to do it for you, such as [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), then your example would look something like this:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "updateSal.php",
   type: "POST",
   data: { sal : $("salary").val() },
   success: function(){
      alert("update");
   }
});
```

Comment: `encodeURI()` will not encode `~!@#$&*()=:/,;?+'`, use `encodeURIComponent()` instead.