# POST Method replacing the '+' characters

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, post

Hei. I am using the POST method for sending some information from a JSP to a Servlet. I cannot understand why when I send through the POST method a "+" character, it will be replace with a space character. Example: when I type the following String:
4+5 -> the Servlet will return 4 5; it replaces all the "+" signs. How can I fix this thing? I really need the "+" characters to be visible because after that I need to evaluate the expressions .

Comment: "+" is a special character. In an URL, you need to encode it replacing it with "%2B". Here is a list a special chars replacements: http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm

Comment: @BenoitCourtine The data are being sent via POST, not as part of a URL. However, the post is most likely being sent with content-type of application/x-www-form-urlencoded, which makes your basic point still valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Form variables are sent URL encoded.  The "+" plus character is (one) URL encoding of a space.

See also:
[AJAX POST and Plus Sign ( + ) -- How to Encode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373414/ajax-post-and-plus-sign-how-to-encode)

If you want to send a literal plus sign, you would need to URL encode it either through Javascript or hard-coded "%2B".

Answer (score 1):

You need to `URLEncode` your data before sending it to the server. The server is trying to decode unencoded data -- the result is that `+` is decoded to a space.

Answer (score 1):

The servlet is evidently expecting the data to arrive with URL encoding, as described in the [W3 document on HTTP form submission](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.3.3). You need to either change your content-type for the POST or (better) encode the data you are sending. You can encode the "+" signs as "%2B".

Answer (score 1):

When encoding URLs, the `+` character indicates a space. If you need to use this character in a URL, you'll have to escape it like this:

```
4+5
```

Becomes

```
4%2B5
```