# C# WebBrowser Encoding Change + to Space

Tags: c#, utf-8

I have the following code as part of a `System.Windows.Forms.Form` using a `WebBrowser` control  in C#:

```
byte[] parameterbyte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(webPost.PostData);

browser.Navigate(new Uri(webPost.Url), String.Empty, parameterbyte, string.Format("Content-Type: {0}", webPost.ContentType) + ";charset=utf-8");
```

In the `webPost.PostData`, I have some value like:

```
MRz2DG0xlu0ucbwzOLXFDoKrmHRFxdi1x6sAU5+E+RcQrjqzGBP1zfBr8XvhoG9YrSd8NwY
```

However, when `browser.Navigate` is executeed, in Fiddler I see the `+` sign was replace by space. Everything else is fine. I tried all different encodings and values, but cannot resolve the issue. Does anyone has a clue?

Comment: Possibly related: [application/x-www-form-urlencoded](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1). Spaces and the plus sign do have a relation.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373414/ajax-post-and-plus-sign-how-to-encode