# + (plus) sign in Web API routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I'm working with an asp.net web api project, and I have to pass an mobile number through a post. But i cannot return a plus sign.

my route:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( 
    name: "SmsRoute",
    routeTemplate: "rest/sms/{country}/{company}/phone/{mobilenumber}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Sms", action = "PostSms" });
```

controller:

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostSms(string country, string company, string mobilenumber)
{
    return Request.CreateResponse( HttpStatusCode.Created );
}
```

When I run this post method on fiddler:

```
http://index.html/rest/sms/se/company/phone/46700101010/messages/out
```

I'm getting this response:

[image]

But I want it to be able to show me the plus sign.

Answer (score 27):

IIS prevents plus-signs from being in URL path elements.

To disable this feature, in `web.config`:

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true" />
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: This worked for me and my problem where UTC dates with a positive time zone would fail. (ie: `/Contacts/LastModified/2020-04-06T08:00:00+02:00`)

Answer (score 2):

This a common anomaly that we face while adding parameters in the url's. Here  you can have a hint of what your OP is and what you might need at a later run

You can have many options as for `+` you can encode in your java script file using

```
encodeURIComponent();
```

And also for your ease if you want to add any special characters in your url like a `.` then simply set the property `relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping` in your web.config

```
<system.web>
<httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />
```

Or you can just add or remove some of the characters to block/allow  using `requestPathInvalidCharacters` in your `web.config`

```
<httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="&lt;,&gt;,*,%,&amp;,:,\,?"/>
```

Comment: This is a WebAPI question.

Comment: The list of characters forbidden by `relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping` is `<, >, :, ", /, \, |, ? and *`. The default value of `requestPathInvalidCharacters` is `<, >, *, %, &, :, \, ?`. Neither of those have any effect on plus-signs, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

Encode the `+`:

Replace your feedle input with this one:

> http://index.html/rest/sms/se/company/phone/%2B46700101010/messages/out

Also see: [AJAX POST and Plus Sign ( + ) -- How to Encode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373414/ajax-post-and-plus-sign-how-to-encode)

http://www.google.com/search?q=foo%2Bbar

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but its not encoding

Comment: What happens when you use the given example ?

Comment: Encoding works in the query string, but not in the URL path components.