# Controller doesn’t accept UTC dates where time zone is a positive

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, datetime, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a controller to get all contacts where the last modified date is greater than or equal to the supplied date.

```
[HttpGet("LastModified/{lastModified:datetime}")]
```

This controller works if you submit a UTC date where the time zone is a negative (ie: Eastern Daylight Time is UTC-4). For example, this call successfully returns data (as expected):

```
/Contacts/LastModified/2020-04-06T08:00:00-04:00
```

The same controller **fails** with a "not found" response if the UTC date has a time zone in the positive (ie: Central European Summer Time is UTC+2). For example, this call fails:

```
/Contacts/LastModified/2020-04-06T08:00:00+02:00
```

Why does the `+` in the date cause a 404 not found? And what is the correct way to accept UTC dates?

(FYI: I even tried replacing the `+` in the URL with a `%2B` during testing, but it didn't work)

Comment: How can you tell when you are going to modify a file in the future?

Comment: Could be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26120919/plus-sign-in-web-api-routing ("IIS prevents plus-signs from being in URL path elements."), but you don't say if it is IIS or not (likely not as you have net.core, probably meaning .Net7)

Comment: @jdweng, It's not in the future. It's in 2020. The `+` is an offset from UTC. You know, time zones.   So right now, it's ...T16:30:00-03:00, but it's also ...T21:30:00+02:00

Comment: The solution was to allow the + sign in the URL: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28228717/6587248