# why replaced plus in string by space

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using ajax to send data through an AJAX call to set.php:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "ajax/set.php",
    dataType: "html",
    type: 'POST',
    data: "data=" + data,
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result);

    }
});
```

Before sending the AJAX call, I am using JavaScript to `alert()` the data, the data is:

```
JeCH+2CJZvAbH51zhvgKfg==
```

But when I use `$_POST["data"]`, the data is:

```
JeCH 2CJZvAbH51zhvgKfg==
```

Which displays pluses replaced with spaces, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [AJAX POST and Plus Sign ( + ) -- How to Encode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373414/ajax-post-and-plus-sign-how-to-encode)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using `$.ajax`, use an object rather than a string with the `data:` option. Then jQuery will URL-encode it properly:

```
data: { data: data },
```

If you really want to pass a string, you should use `encodeURIComponent` on any values that might contain special characters:

```
data: 'data=' + encodeURIComponent(data),
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to encode that `+` with its URL Encoded value `%2B`.

To do this, use the `replace` method.

```
var data = data.replace(/\+/g, "%2B");
```

Comment: Better to use `encodeURIComponent`, so that all special characters will be replaced, not just `+`.

Comment: That is very true. I guess my answer is just solely focused. If anyone uses my answer, you really should use `encodeURIComponent` instead to account for all special characters

Comment: No problem, I think the other folks have better/more accurate answers though. Did any of them work for you yet?

Answer (score 1):

Taking a look at [the jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), you can pass an object to `data` instead of the actual query built by hand. Try:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "ajax/set.php",
    dataType: "html",
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        data: data
    },
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result);

    }
});
```