# Not able to create image from base64string on MVC action method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image-uploading, filereader

I'm trying to upload image in MVC controller by its content.

```
$scope.imageUpload = function (event) {
        var files = event.target.files; //FileList object
        fileString = event.target.files[0];
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            var file = files[i];
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = $scope.imageIsLoaded;
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
    }
    $scope.imageIsLoaded = function (e) {
        $scope.$apply(function () {
            $scope.userProfilePic = e.target.result;
            $.ajax({
                url: "FileUploadWithAjax",
                type: "POST",
                data: 'imageString=' + e.target.result.split(',')[1],
                processData: false
            });
        });
    }
```

Once the image is loaded, I'm sending its content to MVC controller.

```
[System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
        public void FileUploadWithAjax([FromBody]string imageString)
        {
           bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(imageString);
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
            {
                Image image = Image.FromStream(ms);
                image.Save("myBlargyImage.jpg");
            }
        }
```

But it's breaking while creating image from stream.
It throws an error called "Invalid parameter".

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   System.Drawing.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Parameter is not valid.

**Stack Trace**

> at System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Stream stream, Boolean
>   useEmbeddedColorManagement, Boolean validateImageData)    at
>   System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Stream stream)    at
>   Micraft.BBraun.Controllers.EmployeeController.FileUploadWithAjax(String
>   imageString) in D:\B Braun\mvc 31 JAN
>   2017\Micraft.BBraun\Controllers\EmployeeController.cs:line 351    at
>   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0(ControllerBase
>   controller, Object[] parameters)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase
>   controller, Object[] parameters)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.b__39(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3d()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()

**UPDATE**

I was just checking online tool which can generate image from base64string like
http://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter

When I copied image text from its source in html, I was able to generate Image on above site.

After that I tried to copy image content which I was getting on my server side method and surprisingly I was not able to generate image.

Then I compared both texts and found some diferences

If you check bellow image carefully, I can see some changes like wherever there's any "+" sign in Image content, its replaced with "blank space".

is there any content type I'm missing that I should use while posting this data to server?

[image: Right side data are working(copied from client side - left side data are not working copied from server side method)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) on the data sent to server. So, in your ajax request, do as follows:

```
data: 'imageString=' + encodeURIComponent(e.target.result.split(',')[1]),
```

See [AJAX POST and Plus Sign ( + ) -- How to Encode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373414/ajax-post-and-plus-sign-how-to-encode)

Comment: But now its throwing another error, while creating Image from memory stream.

it says `A generic error occurred in GDI+.`

Comment: Hm.. I would wrap `Image image = ...` in a `using` statement. Also check where the file is being saved (if permissions are ok).

Comment: Should I mention path in `image.save("D:\path\ofMyImage.png")` ?

Comment: I would. Maybe the path should be a configurable setting. It really depends on what you do with the image.

Comment: Also, try specifiying format of the image as the second argument to `Save` method.