# Symbols inside values breaking if statements in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have a web app where if someone selects something in the dropdown menu, it changes the next field with Ajax. I'm having difficulty when the values of the dropdown have a '+' symbol which breaks it.

For example this works:

```
if ($_GET['ch'] == 'Something here - here') {}
```

However this does not

```
if ($_GET['ch'] == 'Something here + here') {}
```

I'd like a solution to be able to include the + symbol inside. Some symbols seem to work fine including brackets (), dashes -, etc.

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: not sure how it would matter, but is it because of encoding? Did you log what the string is?

Comment: Try using `POST` instead.

Comment: What if you escape the special characters?

Comment: You need to use encodeURIComponent

Comment: try using urldecode() on your value

Answer (score 0):

Try [encodeURI](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURI.asp) function, and/or use POST instead.
Also escaping characters would be good. (like `\+` instead of `+`)
When you are escaping characters than at php side you should use [stripslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) function if you need special characters.

Comment: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373414/ajax-post-and-plus-sign-how-to-encode?noredirect=1&lq=1) answer, there is no need to decode in PHP as it is already decoded when you use `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_REQUEST`.

Comment: @Script47 Sorry for mistake, just fixed it.